# ANTLR4 : Island grammar, token matching / skipping

Tags: parsing, antlr4

If fighting an island grammar with antlr4, and while I can make it work, I still have doubts if this is the "proper" way.

I need to parse :

```
Some random text
{ }

@if(condition) {
   more random text
   @foobar
   @if (condition2) {
        random text {}
   }
}
```

The problem lies within the context : An "wild" {} isn't anything, but if it's a { } behind a language operator, the { } become meaningful. (read : It opens and closes a block)

In the above case, it would return the following, assuming that condition and condition2 are both true :

```
Some random text
{}
more random text
random text {}
```

I'm confused on which route to pick, any advice on the above ?

The original implementation seems to be matching braces :

```
{ }

@if (true) {
    { 
    foo 
    bar  
    } }
```

yields

```
{ }
{
foo
bar
}
```

while

```
{ }

@if (true) {
{ 
    foo 
    bar  
    }
```

yields a parse error.

Comment: Could you post the ANTLR grammar you've been working on?

Comment: Parser / lexer are at : 

https://github.com/igmar/rythm2/blob/master/src/main/antlr4/RythmLexer.g4
https://github.com/igmar/rythm2/blob/master/src/main/antlr4/RythmParser.g4

I've not implemented the parts referring to the question, since I'm still thinking about the right approach.

Comment: To make clear what I mean : The current parser fails at 

{ }

as an input. Logical : it returns CURLY_OPEN CURLY_CLOSE, which isn't allowed according to the grammar. I could put this in a mode, which isn't easy, since I need to be able to escape it. Basically, I want to say : Match } if you've seen a { first.

Comment: The `{` and `}` in the input `random text {}` are rather ambiguous. How do you make a distinction between the `}` in `random text {}` and the `}` that close a block? If they occur alone on a single line (as the last 2 `}`s), should they then become `CURLY_CLOSE`? If you can explain it in plain English, I might be able to help :)

Comment: The original implementation seems to be counting braces. See https://gist.github.com/igmar/711974fe25eb834360e23e836c26b85c for some examples (I really can't get along with MD).

Comment: I'm reading through The same token must sometimes be ignored and sometimes be recognized
by the parser. in the ANTLR4 guide. I'll post any updates

Comment: You seem to be reverse engineering an existing parser, but you're not entirely clear what the exact rules are. It's hard telling a computer/parser how to handle things you yourself aren't entirely sure of :). I'd start by looking at the source of the existing parser and/or ask the people who wrote it for clues.

Comment: It's actually a Razor-alike implememtation. I've opted for predicated in this case.

Answer (score 0):

this can be solved with a context specific lexer. In this case, by keeping track of the condition / block openings, we can determine if this is template content, or an actual block opening / closing.

See p219 of the ANTLR4 definitive ANTLR4 reference.

Comment: It get's even worse :

text @foo.bar text
text @foo.bar() text is also valid.